# Selected state cleared UIButton in UICollectionViewCell on deleteItemsAtIndexPaths

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have a `UIButton` in a `UICollectionViewCell`.

When the `UIButton` is pressed, I clear the selected state and then remove that cell from the `UICollectionView` using `deleteItemsAtIndexPaths`. This works perfectly except for one thing.

After the cell is deleted, the cell underneath slides up. That cell's UIButton selected state changes from selected -> unselected. Seems like it's picking up the selected state from the original cell?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem...
I tried to remove the cell first, but then used the indexpath to unselect the button.

Problem is that because the cell was removed, the indexpath pointed to the cell underneath..

dumb order of operations bug

Answer (score 0):

You should use a model to control the button's state, because the cell will reuse
every cell for indexpath should be binded with a model.

```
// control button selected state
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isSelected;
cell.button.selected = model.isSelected,
```